# How does Spark determine the number of slave node simultaneous threads?

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark

The two relevant parameters seem to me to be `spark.default.parallelism` and `spark.cores.max`.

`spark.default.parallelism` sets the number of partitions of the in-memory data, and `spark.cores.max` sets the number of available CPU cores.  However, in traditional parallel computing, I would specifically launch some number of threads.

Will Spark launch one thread per partition, regardless of the number of available cores?  If there are 1 million partitions, will Spark limit the number of threads to some reasonable multiple of the number of available cores?

How is the number of threads determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The two relevant parameters seem to me to be `spark.default.parallelism` and `spark.cores.max`.

There are almost completely irrelevant.

Number of data processing threads on each worker depends mostly on three factors:

- Number of cores (threads) which particular worker advertises.

  This is the  maximum number of threads used at the time, not including threads used for secondary purposes. Determined by `CORES` (*advertised* parallelization capability) in standalone mode, and equivalent properties in other cluster managers.
- Number of cores allocated on this worker to executors.

  This is the  maximum number of threads that active applications can actually use (less or equal the first number).
- Number of active tasks scheduled on the executors assigned to this particular worker.

  This is the actual number of threads used at the time. Less or equal to the previous number.

This assumes that the application is honest, and uses only the allocated cores and tasks don't attempt to starts threads, which have not been requested with `spark.task.cpus`.

Comment: Judging from this, is it safe to assume that the maximum number of threads that an "honest" application will use is <= the number of cpu cores?  e.g. if I set CORES to 100000000, I will get at most 8 threads on an 8 core machine?

Comment: Also cores are != threads.  Please clarify your answer to turn the downvote into an upvote.

Comment: Core in Spark is __an alias for thread__. We don't manage "physical" processor cores here, but declared parallelism capability. 8 core worker is free to advertise 1000 `CORES` - you can start with old but still good https://youtu.be/7ooZ4S7Ay6Y?t=1h53m33s _I will get at most 8 threads on an 8 core machine_ - no. You'll get at most advertised `CORES` threads.

Comment: In practice, on dedicated Spark nodes, we usually oversubscribe `CORES` in respect to physical cores, to minimize CPU wait time, during shuffles, and spills.

Comment: what does "all available cores" mean then?  Will spark just spin up threads ad infinitum?  From the spark docs [1] "SPARK_WORKER_CORES: Total number of cores to allow Spark applications to use on the machine (default: all available cores)."

Comment: Default is whatever [`Runtime.availableProcessors()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors--) returns. In other words _number of processors available to the Java virtual machine_. Whatever processor mean in the particular context (physical core, threading capability, ...)

Comment: So setting `SPARK_WORKER_CORES` to 1000 will get me 1000 threads (assuming 1000 tasks running) even if `Runtime.availableProcessors()` returns, say, 4?

Comment: It looks like setting `SPARK_WORKER_CORES` to 1000 will indeed get me 1000 threads.  Here is some of the spark code that's relevant:  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/76b8b840ddc951ee6203f9cccd2c2b9671c1b5e8/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2654

Here is more:  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3f958a99921d149fb9fdf7ba7e78957afdad1405/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/worker/WorkerArguments.scala#L44